# the graph of f(x) = a + b.sin(cx + d), for d not null

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a problem: the graph of $f(x) = a + b.sin(cx + d)$, for d not null do not work in tikz/pgfplot. Can anyone help, please.

The problem, I think, is that I don't know how tikz/pgfplot convert to degree. I've tried (sin(\x + d) r); (sin((\x r) + (d r))) and other variations, but this do not working.

Comment: Could you provide your code and specify what is not working?

Comment: Don't close this

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Hi MWijnand, the important ine in my code is that: \draw[orange,smooth,samples=100,domain = 0:6.28318] plot(\x,{ sin(\x r + 1.047196) r });

Comment: @LuísJoséSousa Please provide a minimal working example -- something we can compile on our end to see the problem so we can fix it without making assumptions about how you have things set up.

Answer (score 6):

I think it might be easiest to use PGFPlots for this, instead of the TikZ `\draw plot` mechanism. You can tell PGFPlots to use radians for trigonometric functions by setting `trig format plots=rad`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
    domain=0:2*pi,
    axis lines=middle,
    enlargelimits=true,
    trig format plots=rad
]
\addplot [orange, thick, samples=100] {sin( x + 1.047196 )};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

If you do want to use plain TikZ for this, you need to use `\draw plot (\x, {sin( (\x + 1.047196)r });` (converting the whole expression inside `sin(...)` from radians to degrees):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [orange, thick] plot [samples=100, domain=0:2*pi] (\x, {sin( (\x + 1.047196)r });
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, Jake. I'll use pgfPLOT code from now on! Thank you!!

Comment: @LuísJoséSousa: Glad it helped! Welcome to the site

Comment: @LuísJoséSousa, also consider to accept it as an answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the `datavisualization` library to plot your graph:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \datavisualization [school book axes,
                        visualize as line=sin,
                        sin={style={thick, orange}}
                       ]
    data[set=sin, format=function] {
      var x : interval [0:2*pi] samples 100;
      func y = sin((\value{x} + 1.047196) r);
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For the explanation of the position of the rad `r` see Jake's answer.

[image: rendered image]